# How to load properties on junit test

Tags: spring, properties

briefly explanation about my project is rest api based on Spring MVC framework. I used profile to package depends on server env.

My project works fine when I run command “mvn package -Plocal”. It works ok.

The problem is when I run junit test, it says that classpath resource cannot be opened.

I just added these annotation

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations=“file:mypath/context.xml)
```

My context.xml file also include propertyplaceholderconfugurator.

```
<property name=locations”>
<list>
<value>/WEB-INF/classes/properties/repository.properties</value>
<value>/WEB-INF/config/common.properties</value>
</list>
<property>
```

Those real path is

```
src/main/resources/build.properties/{dev, local, prod}
sec/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/common.properties
```

I think when I run test, the properties is not loaded on that path. 
Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: did you try adding @TestPropertySource("classpath:common.properties")  in your test class and test

Comment: I tried, but not working. I changed my contextConfigLocation in web.xml. “/WEB-INF/path/spring-context.xml” to “classpath*:*-context.xml”. It look works